# Rails Paperclip - Can't get thumbnail to resize properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm having difficulty creating a thumbnail, for some reason it's not chopping off the way I want. I typically post landscape photos so the dimensions are correct, however when the photo has to be auto rotated, it's not working.

```
has_attached_file  :image, :styles => {   :mobile_lg => "640x480>",
                                          :mobile_sm => "200x150#",
                                          :thumb => "96x96#"
                                          },
                   :convert_options => { :all => '-auto-orient' },
                   :storage => :s3,
                   :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                   :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
```

Don't laugh at the pic, it's my only example! Here's the `mobile_lg` photo.

[image]

and the `mobile_sm` photo:

[image]

When the thumbnail should be like this (i cropped it like this in Photoshop)

[image]

I've tried to add this after the styles, but it's not working.

```
:commands => { :mobile_sm => "-gravity center -extent 200x150#" }
```

I would like to take the photo and crop/resize it to 200(width) by 150(height), even if it means doing it destructively. I've also tried to use `!` after the dimensions, but still I get the mobile_sm image you see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like:

```
:small =>  { :mobile_sm => '150x200!', :quality => 70, :format => 'JPG'}
```

Have a look here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

It sums up everything you can do with ImageMagick used by Paperclip.

BTW, I like the pic ;)